# OSGI Bundle using Android API is showing "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! at android.util.Log.d"

Tags: android, osgi, logcat, android-logcat, osgi-bundle

In my eclipse plugin project, I am trying to use the Android API. I am only showing a message on the LogCat.

In addition to adding `Android.jar` to my class path, I prepared `Android.jar` as a bundle by follwing [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/ConvertAJarIntoOsgiBundle.html) link. So I did the following:

1- Writing the MANIFEST.txt which contains the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: myself
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: android
Bundle-Description: Package android in an OSGi bundle
Bundle-Version: 4.4.0
Bundle-ClassPath: .,android.jar
Bundle-SymbolicName: android
Export-Package: android.util
```

2- Creating the bundle jar file by running the following command:

```
jar cvfm android-bundle.jar manifest.txt android.jar
```

3- Now that I have the bundle `android-bundle.jar`, I open it in eclipse by `File-> New -> Project...-> Plug-in Development -> "Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives"`

Next, I create the bundle that will use the android API. Below is the Activator class which has a Log message:

```
package osgi_android_bundle;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;


import android.util.Log;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private static BundleContext context;

    static BundleContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = bundleContext;


        System.out.println("Hello World. I am the OSGI_Android_Bundle!");

        Log.d("Zaid Log", "Hello World. I am the OSGI_Android_Bundle!!");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = null;


        System.out.println("Goodbye World. I am the OSGI_Android_Bundle!");

        Log.d("Zaid Log", "Goodbye World. I am the OSGI_Android_Bundle!!");
    }

}
```

And also my MANIFEST.MF for the bundle which uses the Android API:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: OSGI_Android_Bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: OSGI_Android_Bundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: osgi_android_bundle.Activator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0", android.util
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

When I run this bundle, I get these errors at the line that prints the message on the Log.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in osgi_android_bundle.Activator.start() of bundle OSGI_Android_Bundle.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:7)
    at osgi_android_bundle.Activator.start(Activator.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:7)
    at osgi_android_bundle.Activator.start(Activator.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY OSGI_Android_Bundle 4 0 2013-08-12 21:34:21.528
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in osgi_android_bundle.Activator.start() of bundle OSGI_Android_Bundle.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.setBundleSL(StartLevelManager.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:7)
    at osgi_android_bundle.Activator.start(Activator.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 9 more
Root exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:7)
    at osgi_android_bundle.Activator.start(Activator.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.setBundleSL(StartLevelManager.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This copy of `android.util.Log` appears to be saying that's it's only a stub, rather than a real implementation. Probably it was created purely for compiling against, and is not expected to be used at runtime.

**UPDATE**:
The following stackoverflow question appears to confirm my guess: [Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! in Android with Fitnesse testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982631/error-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub-in-android-with-fitnesse-testing)

Are you actually running on an Android device or emulator?? It seems you may be running on the standard JVM.

Comment: So are you telling me the log message in this bundle should work when launched on android device or emulator? Because it does not. The bundle is started on the emulator successfully, but that message does not appear on the logCat.

Comment: I didn't say that at all. I said that the android.jar you have used is only a set of stub methods, intended for compilation not runtime. You need to find a real implementation of the API, and I suspect that a real implementation only exists on Android (device or emulator).

Comment: Is the real implementation of android available online? I searched but it's not clear if one exists.

Comment: I wouldn't know about that, but I suspect it's provided by the base platform.

Comment: or it's actually here: http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/plugins/