# How to use pre-trained .model file for predictions in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, classification, weka

I have trained a Decision Table ML model in Weka 3.8 Dekstop Version. I have saved the model accordingly in my assets folder and configured the wekaSTRIPPED.jar file as well. At this point, the build seems to be working fine on Android Studio. However, when I try to use the classification model in Java, I am getting some red highlights - errors - over my code which I am unable to autofix.

I have visited some online guides [here](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/) and visited this commonly used weka-android reference [here](https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android) and [here](https://github.com/davidmascharka/LIPS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/davidmascharka/lips/TrackerActivity.java). They follow the same structure as what I have been doing in my code (with different models), but mine does not compile in Android Studio.

```
package com.example.owner.introductoryapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.rules.DecisionTable;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.DenseInstance;
import weka.core.Instances;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.start();
    }
    public void start() throws Exception {
        //LOADS THE MODEL...
        String rootPath = "/assets/";
        String fileName = "PGBD_DecisionTableUPD.model";
        //Classifier cls = null;
        Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(rootPath + fileName);
```

I expect the output to simply build; I don't expect any prediction output because I haven't specified the testing data-set. However, when I do click compile, none of the terms are highlighted red on the screen.

Specifically, immediately after I run it, I get `Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.` in the build console followed by:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe" -Didea.launcher.port=64163 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar;C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res;C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\IntroductoryApplication\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\compileDebugJavaWithJavac\classes;C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\IntroductoryApplication\app\build\generated\res\rs\debug;C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\IntroductoryApplication\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\customview-28.0.0.aar\14e09720fc7f657365dec6e786490d47\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\localbroadcastmanager-28.0.0.aar\d791f241c61f09475b5d43561b131f77\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\c8f91860fd6811b7040ad585c1bb749f\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\interpolator-28.0.0.aar\73289dbc6711e8292415efe83a859a43\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-28.0.0.aar\2dc7d30dd7abd1c4b0846462e1137cc4\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-28.0.0.aar\b5199754cf7a7bf403b3073b69edcfe3\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\IntroductoryApplication\app\libs\wekaSTRIPPED.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\slidingpanelayout-28.0.0.aar\32aa91f4149120a8a428b24c5291b432\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewmodel-1.1.1.aar\3477f32913f9b9934a8185f031c05533\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\drawerlayout-28.0.0.aar\bfb4eb97f205f1db9a43db5a200619a5\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\coordinatorlayout-28.0.0.aar\aba273524bbeff5bfab162bc52fb07b9\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\coordinatorlayout-28.0.0.aar\aba273524bbeff5bfab162bc52fb07b9\res;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\collections\28.0.0\c1bcdade4d3cc2836130424a3f3e4182c666a745\collections-28.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\documentfile-28.0.0.aar\e49f57095504cc48cc7ba2b26757daf1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.3.aar\96728e03169a340c5e642682fbd18ff8\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.3.aar\96728e03169a340c5e642682fbd18ff8\res;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0.aar\a560a21fcde6d062081d9c09634c92a8\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\cursoradapter-28.0.0.aar\733ca7f2a61e46bdb2164e238fe8c4b6\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\asynclayoutinflater-28.0.0.aar\f950d05bc8679714fb0d7642259e29eb\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-1.1.1.aar\400a5420ad5e4bcef8ebbebf2123e101\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.core\common\1.1.1\e55b70d1f5620db124b3e85a7f4bdc7bd48d9f95\common-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar\12c3dd068050bf0422d8455749982d52\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.1.aar\68e9f88e3e623f899ee79dd4aa8966f1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\print-28.0.0.aar\f12fdac753fb8cbf34b55eced23a29c7\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\loader-28.0.0.aar\0f1fa1caaba4127fdcb1d7bb76f1c144\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewpager-28.0.0.aar\bdf7976216feddc6d17d8052bf1807db\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-28.0.0.aar\df9931f8c3d84779819dccebe1aa6282\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\support-annotations\28.0.0\ed73f5337a002d1fd24339d5fb08c2c9d9ca60d8\support-annotations-28.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\common\1.1.1\207a6efae6a3555e326de41f76bdadd9a239cbce\common-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-core-1.1.1.aar\f5b8b9e2bbbf6e16caa00d091d538f2f\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\0fefdb1435b453663f8b867197d75a41\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\0fefdb1435b453663f8b867197d75a41\res;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\7eca742b05d3ca93c5f22855deb68690\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\b5690672012030cd411a187af3fc56e5\res;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\b5690672012030cd411a187af3fc56e5\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support.constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.1.3\bde0667d7414c16ed62d3cfe993cff7f9d732373\constraint-layout-solver-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Owner\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.1.aar\b33f18eb28c72c82424fc1a72a917596\jars\classes.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2 com.example.owner.introductoryapplication.Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.content.Context.<init>(Context.java:67)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.<init>(ContextWrapper.java:30)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.<init>(ContextThemeWrapper.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:643)
    at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:46)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:62)
    at com.example.owner.introductoryapplication.Test.<init>(Test.java:13)
    at com.example.owner.introductoryapplication.Test.main(Test.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Though, from what I understand, I have already included the .model file in my assets folder; it should recognize the file path.

**So this begs the questions: How would I enable Android Studio to process my `PGBD_DecisionTable.model` file and how would I use it with testing data (directly on the phone)?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `.open("PGBD_DecisionTable.model")` instead of `.open(PGBD_DecisionTable.model)`.

You are trying to load a file from a constant `String` expression, not a static property of a class named `PGBD_DecisionTable`.

Comment: I tried using quotations, however to no success. I have updated my question with a new code snippet and a different error output this time.

Comment: Your error looks like an classpath error. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982631/error-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub-in-android-with-fitnesse-testing this can help you.

Comment: I tried this alternative where I am training the model directly on the Android/Java interface. I read in a question that you can't access .model files (in an app) which were created on a PC. What about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443209/unable-to-access-training-dataset-for-ml-classification-using-weka-in-java? Shouldn't this work?