# Where should I save my file in Android for local access?

Tags: java, android-studio, save, weka, arff

I have two datasets which are currently in the same folder as my java files AND on my PC. Currently, I am accessing them through my C-drive. Since this is an app, where should I save my .ARFF files and what path should I use instead? I have tried in the raw folder, but nothing seems to work.

Here's what I have so far...
[image: Current Code]
[image: Hierarchy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***After too many hours***

A very easy solution to retrieving data from the assets folder! Only one user-defined method.

1. Make `raw` folder in `res` directory.
2. Paste whatever files in the `raw directory`
3. Make a separate `.java` file
4. Make sure it is a derivative class (in this case it extended `AppCompatActivity`
5. Write Part A in the body
6. Write Part B outside the body

**A.** This is in the `main` function OR in a custom, `user-defined` function.

```
BufferedReader bReader;            
bReader = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(ISR(R.raw.FILENAME_WITHOUT_TYPE)));
```

`FILENAME_WITHOUT_TYPE` refers to **only** the name of the file, not its ending (everything followed by the **.**).

**B.** This is the definition of ISR.

```
public InputStream ISR(int resourceId) {
    InputStream iStream = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
    return iStream;
}
```

*Works like a charm!*

Resources:

- https://inducesmile.com/android-programming/how-to-read-a-file-from-raw-directory-in-android/
- https://gist.github.com/Airfixed/799e784696b0a60c5423d347bf33a341

Answer (score 2):

Create a raw directory in your project,  raw is included in the res folder of android project. You can add an assets files in raw folder like music files, database files or text files or some other files which you need to access directly

1) Right click on res folder, select New> Directory, then studio will open a dialog box and it will ask you to enter the name.

2) Enter “raw” and click OK. Open res folder and you will find your raw folder under it.

```
InputStream input = Context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_file_name);
```

// Example to read file from raw directory

```
private String readFileFromRawDirectory(int resourceId)
{
InputStream iStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = null;
try {
byte[] buffer = new byte[iStream.available()];
iStream.read(buffer);
byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byteStream.write(buffer);
byteStream.close();
iStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return byteStream.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: I followed your steps. What is the path I should use? Is it "/raw/JavaTestingSet.arff"?

Comment: `R.raw.JavaTestingSet`

Comment: I get this error. Cannot resolve constructor 'FileReader(int)'. I will definitely use FileReader.

Comment: You can read raw resources with openRawResource(int), this will give you an InputStream which you can wrap with an InputStreamReader, then wrap with a BufferedReader  https://gist.github.com/Airfixed/799e784696b0a60c5423d347bf33a341

Comment: You must trying to read resource , either on some Fragment or some Activity , right ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, though none of your solutions worked. Also, next time, please cite which source you received the code in your solution. For other viewers, the link is: https://inducesmile.com/android-programming/how-to-read-a-file-from-raw-directory-in-android/.