# How to resolve java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! error in .java file?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, weka, assets, stub

I am trying to classify an instance using a .model file which I have created on the Weka GUI. It seems I have successfully classified the test instance, however, I am not sure whether I am able to successfully load my .model file **and** of the Stub compiler error.

I have tried to remove the `extends AppCompatActivity` and if that makes any difference in the .model upload. It turns out that to use `getAssets()`, the code must be in an activity. However, I an still unsure of whether the model has upload and the unusual compiler error. I have followed the basic framework of @davidmascharka's [work on GitHub](https://github.com/davidmascharka/LIPS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/davidmascharka/lips/TrackerActivity.java) (he's also loading a WEKA model from assets), but mine does not compile.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.owner.introductoryapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.rules.DecisionTable;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.DenseInstance;
import weka.core.Instances;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        //LOADS THE MODEL...------------------------------------------------------
        String rootPath = "/assets/";
        String fileName = "PGBD_DecisionTableUPD.model";
        Classifier cls = null;
        try {
            //cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(rootPath + fileName);
            cls = (DecisionTable) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(getAssets().open(fileName));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.content.Context.<init>(Context.java:67)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.<init>(ContextWrapper.java:30)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.<init>(ContextThemeWrapper.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:643)
    at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:46)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:62)
    at com.example.owner.introductoryapplication.Test.<init>(Test.java:13)
    at com.example.owner.introductoryapplication.Test.main(Test.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I expect the program to at least compile! I have absolutely no clue why it's not. I tried switching the order of my dependencies, hoping that would make a difference, but to no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question in being asked already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982631/error-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub-in-android-with-fitnesse-testing

Comment: Hope this will help

Comment: @rishavprasher Thanks for the link. It mentions that I should run this on Android emulator or directly on the device, but I am simply printing it using `System.out` not on device screen.

Comment: your welcome @Shounak Ray

Comment: @rishavprasher So I can't use that to solve my problem...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been covered before, but `weka.jar` **only** allows for Stub implementations. Essentially, you must configure the run setting to "app" instead of a specific file.

If you want to see how a specific file works, then you can use the `debug` option for your app.