# Dialog Fragment does not appear when image is clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog

I (think) I have configured my code such that when an Image is clicked, then it opens a Dialog with some information. However, when I click the image, instead of the Dialog opening, it says that `MY_APP has stopped` on the device screen.

I am using Android studio for this and I don't get any compiler errors there when I `build` my project. However, it doesn't work on the device.

Here's my code:
`UserDataInputActivity.java`

```
package com.example.owner.introductoryapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import android.view.View;


public class UserDataInputActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String[] genderOptions = {"Male", "Female", "Other"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_data_input);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, genderOptions);
        //Find TextView control
        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.GenderPromptValue);
        //Set the number of characters the user must type before the drop down list is shown
        acTextView.setThreshold(1);
        //Set the adapter
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onGenericMenuClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent;

        if(v.getId() == R.id.pasttests)
        {
            intent =  new Intent(this, PastDiagnosticResult.class);
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.currenttest)
        {
            intent =  new Intent(this, CurrentDiagnosticResultActivity.class);
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.myinfo)
        {
            intent =  new Intent(this, UserDataInputActivity.class);
        }
        else //if(v.getId() == R.id.gaitInfoButton)
        {
            intent = new Intent(this, GaitInformation.class);
        }

        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }
}
```

`GaitInformation.java`

```
package com.example.owner.introductoryapplication;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class GaitInformation extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.GaitInformationContent)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.acknowledge, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //GO BACK TO THE USER DATA INPUT PAGE - HOW?
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

`LOGCAT CRUSH REPORT`

```
2019-01-04 14:24:34.741 8385-8385/com.example.owner.introductoryapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.owner.introductoryapplication, PID: 8385
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24802)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6521)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24802) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6521) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.owner.introductoryapplication/com.example.owner.introductoryapplication.GaitInformation}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1940)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1618)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4529)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4848)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4816)
        at com.example.owner.introductoryapplication.UserDataInputActivity.onGenericMenuClick(UserDataInputActivity.java:52)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24802) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6521) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2019-01-04 14:24:35.040 2367-2389/? E/libnav: CablComputeBacklightLevel(): UpdateType = DifferentSceneUpdate
2019-01-04 14:24:35.251 2638-2670/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.owner.introductoryapplication/com.example.owner.introductoryapplication.PastDiagnosticResult/1
2019-01-04 14:24:40.474 2367-2389/? E/libnav: CablComputeBacklightLevel(): UpdateType = DifferentSceneUpdate
```

I expect the dialog to pop-up, but - instead - it says my app has stopped working.

Comment: A crush happens in run time, when u click on the image. can u please post the crush report? u will find it in logcat.

Comment: @ZoarderAlMuktadir I have specified the crush report!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open a DialogFragment like this. Please try this.

```
package com.example.owner.introductoryapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import android.view.View;


public class UserDataInputActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String[] genderOptions = {"Male", "Female", "Other"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_data_input);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, genderOptions);
        //Find TextView control
        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.GenderPromptValue);
        //Set the number of characters the user must type before the drop down list is shown
        acTextView.setThreshold(1);
        //Set the adapter
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onGenericMenuClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = null;

        if(v.getId() == R.id.pasttests)
        {
            intent =  new Intent(this, PastDiagnosticResult.class);
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.currenttest)
        {
            intent =  new Intent(this, CurrentDiagnosticResultActivity.class);
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.myinfo)
        {
            intent =  new Intent(this, UserDataInputActivity.class);
        }
        else //if(v.getId() == R.id.gaitInfoButton)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserDataInputActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.GaitInformationContent)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.acknowledge, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //GO BACK TO THE USER DATA INPUT PAGE - HOW?
                            }
                        });
                // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                builder.create().show();
        }

        if (intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Al Maktadir I am getting the same error output: `error: variable intent might not have been initialized`. How can I fix this? After the user closes the `Dialog`, it should return to `UserDataInputActivity`'s screen...

Comment: It works; thank you. Can you go over what you changed?

Comment: Just initialize the intent object with null.

Comment: Ok gotcha. @Zoarder Al Muktadir Could you also take a look at these questions, I have been having a lot of trouble as well. I believe its a simple solution...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036101/how-to-resolve-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub-error-in-java-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983231/how-to-use-pre-trained-model-file-for-predictions-in-android-studio. Lastly, an upvote would be nice! : )

Comment: Ok, Let me Check... Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
intent = new Intent(this, GaitInformation.class);
```

into this

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
GaitInformation dialog = new GaitInformation();
dialog.show(manager, "dialog");
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Error output is: `error: variable intent might not have been initialized`. It makes sense because the last `else` condition doesn't initialize `Intent`, as opposed to the other conditional above.

Comment: Try this to start the intent 
Intent intent = null;

Comment: It works; thanks! Can you tell me what's going on in the above code?

Comment: In your if else block default behaviour was not initializing the intent. Just to prevent that error we passed null. So it was initialized after that but just the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

In your class GaitInfomation on line 
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
You have to pass valid context which I suspect is null looking at the code.

Update: Instead of launching a new activity

```
      else //if(v.getId() == R.id.gaitInfoButton) {
          AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                  setMessage(R.string.GaitInformationContent)
                 .setPositiveButton(R.string.acknowledge, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //GO BACK TO THE USER DATA INPUT PAGE - HOW?
                    return;
                    }
               });
                 .create()
                .show()
           }
```

Comment: How do I pass the "valid context"? Can you provide a code snippet so I understand what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: Knivasara Please see https://imgur.com/7wploeS - it shows what my your code looks like on my IDE. As for when I run it, I get `error: <identifier> expected`, `error: ';' expected`, and `error: illegal start of expression` in many places.